# jQuery loading twice

Tags: jquery

I am creating joomla templates and want to add a simple jquery script. The problem is that there are other joomla extensions like GCalendar which load their own jquery.

This means:

1. If I add `<script src="http://code.jquery.co....` it will conflict with the jquery of other extensions
2. If I don't add that code, the new script will not work if other jquery loading extensions are not installed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you are hosting the library yourself you could wrap the entire library with an

```
if ( !jQuery ) {
    // jQuery Library
}
```

Or you could look into a library like RequireJS to handle your dependencies.

Comment: the if didn;t work or I don't know how to use it. How can I add something like "if jquery is loaded do nothing but if there is no jquery load jquery"

Comment: Currently my code looks like this: `
<script>
if(!window.jQuery)
{
   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.type = "text/javascript";
   script.src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js";
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript">var $j = jQuery.noConflict();</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/myjqueryscript.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

You can check if `jQuery` is defined in script and load it if it has not been loaded prior.

You may run into functionaliy issues if the previously loaded version of jQuery is not a version you are supporting

---

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write(
        '<script src="/scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"><\/script>')
</script>
```

Comment: can you tell me exactly how to do this?